# .NET Office type library enums and narrowing conversions (is there a better way?)

Tags: vb.net, enums, vsto

Using Microsoft Office objects in VB.NET projects with Option Strict On, just using an Office type library enum like this:

```
Dim vsoShape as Visio.Shape
Dim UUID as String
UUID = vsoShape.UniqueID(Visio.VisUniqueIDArgs.visGetOrMakeGUIDWithUndo)
```

will, because the enums are As Integer and the argument is a Short/Int16, give this error:

Error   BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'VisUniqueIDArgs' to 'Short'.

Solving this error everywhere these Enums are used as arguments (and that is a lot of code, thousands of lines, often 3 Enum arguments in one line of code):

```
UUID = vsoShape.UniqueID(CShort(Visio.VisUniqueIDArgs.visGetOrMakeGUIDWithUndo))
```

with a CShort() explicit conversion works but is not very elegant and makes the code less readable.

Is there a more elegant solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a corresponding [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.visuniqueidargs) in your code as short and thus avoid any further conversions at runtime.

Comment: Thank you Eugene good to know that is the only way to make it simpler, doing a CShort explicit type conversion every time is really silly so this is a better solution.

Comment: @DotNETFan If this solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.